# Off-center conducting sphere in larger conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

The following steps are performed:

- A conducting shell of radius $r$ is charged to a charge $q$.
- This sphere is placed inside a larger conducting shell (radius $R$) such that the center of the small shell is a distance $R/2$ from the center of the bigger shell.
- I know that there will be a negative non-uniform charge distributed on the inner surface of the big shell (call this shell 2 and the small one shell 1) and a uniform positive charge on the outer surface so that the field outside shell 2 is as if $q$ were at its center.
- The charge distribution on shell 1 will also change and become non-uniform

What I want to know is that given the following conditions:

- Shell 1 is an equipotential
- Shell 2 is an equipotential
- Field inside shell 1 is $0$ $\Rightarrow$ sum of fields due to non uniform charge $-q$ on inner surface of shell 2 and the (now) nonuniform charge $+q$ on shell 1 is zero

  - inside shell 1
  - outside shell 2

Given this information, how would one deduce the charge distributions on the inner surface of shell 2 and on shell 1?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Note that questions of the form "Is this right?" tend to be poor first for this site because the answer, yes or no, is too short to be a valid answer. Please consider editing the question to be more open-ended and allow for longer answers.

Comment: Any hints?@sammygerbil